# How do I get the amount of the oldest transaction using the transaction date on both SQL Server and Cognos

Tags: sql-server, cognos-10

I tried getting this result 2834.0000 using the oldest date which is 2010-08-31 13:51:02.000 but I end up getting all dates and its corresponding amount. I only need one row and one column. How do I do this in SQL server and in Cognos Report Studio using a Data Item?

```
select min([Transaction Date]) [Transaction Date], [GWP Amt] [Amount] from DW.AmountTable
where [Policy Number] = '11EEO7030500'
group by [Transaction Date], [GWP Amt]
```

[image]

Comment: when you are using Min function why to use the column name in group by

Comment: Because I get this prompt.   Column DW.AmountTable is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, lose the [Transaction Date] in your GROUP BY clause, as you're getting the Min([Transaction Date]) in the SELECT clause and am not grouping on it.

But if you want only one row with the Min(TransactionDate)and that row's Amount, couple of ways to pull that off, try this one first..

```
SELECT [Transaction Date], Amount
FROM DW.AmountTable
WHERE [Transaction Date] IN (SELECT Min([Transaction Date]) FROM DW.AmountTable)
```

Comment: Close... `Amount` is an alias you need to add  `[GWP amt]` in front of it.  and you're missing his where clause. `where [Policy Number] = '11EEO7030500'` @BongReyes think of this as getting a subset with the earliest transaction date, and then returning only records matching that date.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different way to achieve the desired results:

We create a subset of the data with the min transaction date and policy numbers.  We then join it back to the full set based on the transaction date and policy number.  and then use a where clause to get only the policy in question.  This has an advantage of allowing you to filter by policy number without having to include the policy in two places.

However, it assumes Policy number and transaction date are unique.

```
SELECT A.[Transaction Date], A.[GWP Amt] [Amount] 
FROM DW.AmountTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT min(transaction date) MTD, [Policy Number]) 
            FROM dw.amountTable 
            GROUP BY [Policy Number]) B
 on B.MTD=A.[Transaction Date]
and A.[Policy Number] = B.[Policy Number]
where A.[Policy Number] = '11EEO7030500'
```